# How to check the dismiss of UIPopOverController in iOS?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I need to set the `UIPopOverController` to choose photo from library.

So i write following codes.

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    [self.imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePickerController];

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.btnArchive.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
    imagePickerPopover = popover;
```

It's Appear and i choose one photo from Photo Library and after i have chosen from library i dismiss the PopOver with following codes.

```
[self.imagePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

I need to show the Image that chosen from photo library , so i write following codes in - `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method.

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {

// Codes Here after dismiss PopOverView and chosen photo from library

}];
```

But it doesn't work. How do i check it with `UIPopOverController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController   
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

This are the delegate methods when popover controller dismisses

Answer (score 1):

set the delegates of the popover to self and also you can use two popover delegates i.e

```
/* Called on the delegate when the popover controller will dismiss the popover. Return NO to prevent the dismissal of the view.
 */
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController;
/* Called on the delegate when the user has taken action to dismiss the popover. This is not called when -dismissPopoverAnimated: is called directly.
 */
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController;
```

then set your MainViewController instance as the delegate of the popover

`popover.delegate = self;`